# iOS - How to display values in matrix format(row and Column) in UITableview using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvKRI.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvKRI.jpg - I'm creating an EMI loan App.In that,I want to display user values with another tableview controller in tabular data format.Now im displaying values using label instead of it, i want some other solutions.Thank you

Comment: Why not a collection view?

Comment: can you show some thing in which type do u need

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik -I added a sample Image.Please check it.

Comment: @ Wain - In collection View I can display only in the form of Cells.But here I need to display Rows and Column(see the Image link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve something like in the reference image you have to give this kind of look via custom tableview view cell. Because as there is no such control available . As you data is in each row looks relative to your tier so it will be a bit easy . I have edit your image to give an idea how you should accomplish it.

[image]

Comment: @PrabhaPalanisamy wellcome